# Reuse or cast structs for validation, API results, and DB saves in Go

Tags: validation, go

I'm trying to write an API that will do different things with the data depending on its purpose.

- API results - The API should expose certain fields to the user
- Validation - Validation should handle different schemas e.g. login form doesn't require Name, but register does
- Database - The database should save everything, including password etc. - if I try using the same struct for the API and DB with `json:"-"` or un-exporting the field the database save also ignores the field

Some sample code is below with a couple of comments in capitals to show where I ideally need to type cast to change the data. As they are different structs, they cannot be type cast, so I get an error. How can I fix this?

Alternatively, what is a better way of doing different things with the data without having lots of similar structs?

```golang
// IDValidation for uuids
type IDValidation struct {
    ID string `json:"id" validate:"required,uuid"`
}


// RegisterValidation for register form
type RegisterValidation struct {
    Name     string `json:"name" validate:"required"`
    Email    string `json:"email" validate:"required,email"`
    Password string `json:"password" validate:"required,min=8"`
}

// UserModel to save in DB
type UserModel struct {
    ID        string `json:"id,omitempty"`
    Name      string `json:"name"`
    Email     string `json:"email"`
    Password  string `json:"password,omitempty"`
    Active    bool   `json:"active,omitempty"`
    CreatedAt int64  `json:"created_at,omitempty"`
    UpdatedAt int64  `json:"updated_at,omitempty"`
    jwt.StandardClaims
}

// UserAPI data to display to user
type UserAPI struct {
    ID        string `json:"id,omitempty"`
    Name      string `json:"name"`
    Email     string `json:"email"`
    Active    bool   `json:"active,omitempty"`
}

// register a user
func register(c echo.Context) error {
    u := new(UserModel)
    if err := c.Bind(u); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    // NEED TO CAST TO RegisterValidation HERE?
    if err := c.Validate(u); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    token, err := u.Register()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return c.JSON(http.StatusOK, lib.JSON{"token": token})
}

// retrieve a user
func retrieve(c echo.Context) error {
    u := IDValidation{
        ID: c.Param("id"),
    }
    if err := c.Validate(u); err != nil {
        return echo.NewHTTPError(http.StatusBadRequest, err.Error())
    }
    // NEED TO CAST USER TO UserAPI?
    user, err := userModel.GetByID(u.ID)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return c.JSON(200, lib.JSON{"message": "User found", "user": user})
}
```

Comment: Did you consider using embedding and constructors? Something like this: https://play.golang.org/p/-F0QEt1gHB_9

Comment: @mkopriva Thanks, that looks like an improvement! Is there anyway to shorten or remove the `UserModelFromRegistration` function? Otherwise I have to create one of the functions for every type of form.

Comment: For the cases where you have only one type of validation you can use the model. For the case where you have more than one custom validation, such as your example of login vs register, you'll need a separate struct and then manually create a model from that. Or you can write your own struct to struct binder using the reflect package, but I assume the number of cases where you have multiple custom validations is small compared to those where you have one validation per type... So use model wherever possible, otherwise use one of the two other options.

Comment: Another option would be to redefine the whole struct with different tags and then just convert a value from one type to another. E.g. https://play.golang.org/p/OvuCKsUsyD7

Comment: One more idea: https://play.golang.org/p/3cSSWKR_TrI but I'm not sure whether echo's validation will skip an embedded field if the embedding struct has the same field with `validation:"-"`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a play and see what method works best!